# Different ways to create objects on stack

Tags: c++, constructor

There is a class with a non-default constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {

public:

  Foo(int a) { std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl; };

}
```

So the default constructor couldn't be invoked:

```
   Foo obj; // compilation error
```

The non-default constructor can be inkoved:

```
   Foo obj(1);
```

**Question:**

What happens in the following line that compiles?

```
   Foo obj();
```

Comment: [The most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a function prototype with no parameters.

To be more specific... basically nothing happens

Comment: See also "C Forward Declaration"

Comment: Well something happens, you said that function exists, so you're gonna get strange link-time errors if you accidentally manage to invoke it and haven't provided an implementation.

Comment: sure, but during execution nothing happens, no construction, no stack allocation, nottin, the line has no effect